# Convert each character in a string to a row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a column which contains a String with numbers like '12345' (no separator or blanks) and I want to split this column to rows for each character:

From:

```
 COLUMN
 ------------------
 12345
```

To:

```
 COLUMN
 ------------------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

This Should work in a single select so that I can use it like this:

... AND WHERE SOMECOLUMN NOT LIKE (**... THE SELECT ...**)

Comment: You are working with a very very bad database design for sure

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No need for the downvote because it is indeed a very bad DB design but it is not mine and unchangeable because of the software that sits on top. I'm just trying to add some needed web services ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with temp as (select '12456' as str from dual)
select substr(str,level,1)
from temp
connect by level <= length(str);
```

Result:

```
1
2
4
5
6
```